Pandas: How to append all columns into one with header as value
i would like to append all columns into one and have the headers as a second column.
For Example if i have this dataframe:



Japan
UK
USA




Tokyo
London
NYC


Okinawa
Birmingham
Chicago


NaN
Manchestter
LA


NaN
NaN
Austin



I would like to turn it into this









Tokyo
Japan


Okinawa
Japan


London
UK


Birmingham
UK


Manchester
UK


NYC
USA


Chicago
USA


LA
USA


Austin
USA



So here is the way i am doing this. I am creating a dictionary here, but a dataframe would be good as well.
series_list = [df[x] for x in df]      #list of pd.Series
dic = {}
for i in range(0,len(series_list)):
    for j in range(0, len(series_list[i])):
        if pd.isnull(series_list[i][j]) == False:
            dic[series_list[i][j]] = series_list[i].name


It works fine, but I assume there is a simpler way without the use of a nested for loop if anyone has any ideas. Thanks.
